# FlatList scroll with the static component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have one static component and many for loop rendered components in a screen.

The all code below here.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";
...

class FlatListScrollWithStatic extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FriendsTop />  // the static component
        <FlatList
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          data={this.props.friendsCard}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <FriendsCard {...item} />}  // the for loop rendered components
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Now I want to migrate the FriendsTop into Flatlist, let it scroll with the rendered components, how should I change my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flatlist has a prop `ListHeaderComponent` which accepts a JSX element.
So:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList } from "react-native";
...

class FlatListScrollWithStatic extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

        <FlatList
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          data={this.props.friendsCard}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <FriendsCard {...item} />}  // the for loop rendered components
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          ListHeaderComponent={<FriendsTop />}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I forget react-native flatlist has more props available on it compared to the plain react version one I use.  Good call.

Comment: Your solution works too, but I think this is cleaner.

Comment: Oh, for sure.  I've mostly been doing react development so had to roll my own flatlist based on RN's FlatList with the barest of props to get the rest of my team to adopt it more willingly.

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you:

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

...

<FlatList
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  data={this.props.friendsCard}
  renderItem={({ item }, index) => (
    <Fragment>
      { !index && <FriendsTop /> } // Render when !index is truthy (i.e. index === 0)
      <FriendsCard {...item} />
    </Fragment>
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

Comment: This let the `FriendsTop` scrollable, but also render the `FriendsTop` the same time as the `FriendsCard`.

Comment: Yes, only on the first element (index === 0) does it render into the list a `FriendsTop` component, before the first item.  It'll scroll with the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

i thing there is two way for doing this first using the first using the header component of flatlist

but i guess if you want static data with the data you get from fetch you should combine them

```
 <FlatList
   inverted
      data={this.state.data.concat({
        "id":1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "title": "all",
        "similar_title": null,
        "description": null,
        "font_icon": null,
        "default_distance": 8,
        "visible": "yes",
        "priority": "no",
        "image": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": "2018-06-14 22:13:58"
    })}

      numColumns={4}


      renderItem={({item}) =>
```

in that code i am adding static all button with concat [image]